# Extension may not contain stored property but why is static allowed

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

Extension cannot contain stored property, but why then can static stored property be defined within extension?

I also didn't find any documentation mentioning that static property is allowed in extension.

```
extension String {
  static let test = "Test"
  static var test2 = "Test2"
}
```

Comment: Hmm. The [Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151) only specifically states that *"Extensions in Swift can: Add computed instance properties and computed type properties (...)"* and they never mention that stored type properties are allowed in extensions so I had always assumed they were not. A `static var` works just as well by the way.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Extensions cannot contain stored *instance* properties. Why? Because adding an instance property would change the size of instances of that type. What happens if one module adds an extension such that an `Int` is now 2 words long? What should then happen when it, for example, gets an `Int` from another module where they are still 1 word in size?

The reason why *static* stored properties are permitted in extensions is simply because they have static lifetime; they exist independently of any instances of the given type you're extending. Really they're nothing more than global stored variables, just namespaced to a type. Therefore they can be freely added without affecting code that has already been compiled without knowledge of them.

It's worth noting however that there are currently three restrictions on defining static stored properties.

#### 1. You cannot define a `static` stored property on a generic type

This would require separate property storage for each individual specialisation of the generic placeholder(s). For example, with:

```
struct S<T> {

    static var foo: Int {
        return 5
    }

    static let bar = "" // error: Static stored properties not supported in generic types
}
```

Just as `foo` is called on individual specialisation of `S`, e.g `S<Int>.foo` and `S<Float>.foo` and *not* on `S` itself (in fact; `S` is not even a type currently, it requires that `T` be satisfied); `bar` would (likely) be the same. It would be called as, for example, `S<Int>.bar`, not `S.bar`.

This is an important detail because the metatype that a static member is called on is passed to the receiver as the implicit `self` argument. This is accessible in static property initialiser expressions; therefore allowing them to call other static methods.

Therefore being able to call the same static property initialiser on *different* specialisations of a generic type would have the potential to create different property values for each (consider the simple case of `static let baz = T.self`). Therefore we need separate storage for each of them.

However, that all being said, there's no real reason why the compiler/runtime cannot do this, and it may well do in a future version of the language. Although one argument against this is that it may produce confusing behaviour in some cases.

For example, consider:

```
import Foundation

struct S<T> {
    static let date = Date()
}
```

If the runtime implicitly generated new storage for `date` each time it gets accessed on a new specialisation of `S<T>`, then `S<Float>.date` would not equal `S<Int>.date`; which may be confusing and/or undesirable.

#### 2. You cannot define a `static` stored property in a protocol extension

This mostly follows on from the previous point. A `static` stored property in a protocol extension would require separate storage for each conforming type of that protocol (but again; there's no reason why the compiler/runtime cannot do this).

This is necessary with protocols, as `static` members in protocol extensions are *not* members on the protocol type itself. They are members on concrete types that conform to the protocol.

For example, if we have:

```
protocol P {}

extension P {

    static var foo: Int {
        return 5
    }

    static let bar = "" // error: Static stored properties not supported in generic types
                        // (not really a great diagnostic)
}

struct S : P {}
struct S1 : P {}
```

We cannot access `foo` on the protocol type itself, we cannot say `P.foo`. We can only say `S.foo` or `S1.foo`. This is important because `foo`'s getter can call out to static protocol requirements on `self`; however this isn't possible if `self` is `P.self` (i.e the protocol type *itself*), as [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878).

The same would (likely) follow for `static` stored properties such as `bar`.

#### 3. You cannot define a `class` stored property

I don't believe there would be any problems with such a declaration in the class body itself (it would simply be equivalent to a computed `class` property backed by a `static` stored property).

However it *would* be potentially problematic in extensions, because extensions cannot add new members to a Swift class vtable (though they can add to the Obj-C counterpart if applicable). Therefore in most cases they wouldn't be dynamically dispatched to (so would effectively be `final`, and therefore `static`). Although that being said, `class` *computed* properties are currently permitted in extensions, so it may be permissible in the interests of consistency.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the doc that specifies static is allowed? Or Swift users have to infer that?

Comment: @Boon Good question! I can't find any official documentation specifying it; but we can take a look at the [implementation of the type checker for declarations](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/afd685895b167850621305ec49881fccd8580561/lib/Sema/TypeCheckDecl.cpp#L3978), which notes that "*Enums and extensions cannot have stored instance properties. Static stored properties are allowed, with restrictions enforced below.*" And those restrictions are for 1. Generic types and 2. `class` stored properties. May be worth filing a bug with Apple over not having the documentation mention it.

Comment: excellent answer. Coming from `scala` i'm a bit disappointed in the limitations described here -since they are all handled readily in that language. But that does not diminish the quality of your content.