# Is it a code smell to use private global variables as extension 'properties'?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Because **'Extensions may not contain stored properties'** I've seen people getting around this by using getter / setter with `objc_getAssociatedObject` / `objc_setAssociatedObject`

(See) [How to have stored properties in Swift, the same way I had on Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426780/how-to-have-stored-properties-in-swift-the-same-way-i-had-on-objective-c)

I find the solutions discussed there very 'unswifty' but still like to keep the variables close to where they are used.

That's why I recently started doing the following when I want to use a 'property' in an extension.

```
private var lastValue: Int = 0


extension ViewController {

    func checkIfBiggerThanLastNumber(_ number: Int) -> Bool {

        let savedLast = lastValue
        lastValue = number
        return number > savedLast
    }

}
```

Because I didn't find this solution elsewhere, I wonder if that is a code smell or what drawbacks come with it.

That other extensions in that source file can access `lastValue` is a thing I can live with because the extension is in it's own source file.

Comment: Think about it: What happens if you have *two instances* of that class, and set a value on each of them?

Comment: Well, that's a good point...

Comment: What is the reason why we can't easily add properties to extension?

Comment: Because adding properties changes the size of the object. ViewControllers created in another module would have no way to know how much memory to allocate. Adding that feature would require creating something like objc_getAssociatedObject in Swift, which may be possible some day for classes (though I doubt ever for structs).

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/45495616/1187415: *" Because adding an instance property would change the size of instances of that type"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is commonly done with a dictionary. ("Commonly" meaning "when the ObjC runtime isn't available." As Charles Srstka notes, the correct tool here for a view controller is definitely `objc_getAssociatedObject`. There is no particular virtue in avoiding the runtime once you've already inherited from `NSObject`.)

It leaks some memory (since there's no automatic way to clean out unused values), but the cost is usually small (or you have to add a mechanism to "garbage collect" which isn't too hard).

```
private var lastValues: [ObjectIdentifier: Int] = [:]

extension ViewController {
    private var lastValue: Int {
        get {
            return lastValues[ObjectIdentifier(self)] ?? 0
        }
        set {
            lastValues[ObjectIdentifier(self)] = newValue
        }
    }

    func checkIfBiggerThanLastNumber(_ number: Int) -> Bool {

        let savedLast = lastValue
        lastValue = number
        return number > savedLast
    }
}
```

---

I haven't tested this extensively, but this an example of how you might build an auto-garbage collecting version of this to clean up memory if you had a lot of objects that come and go. It garbage collects every time you modify it, but you could do it other ways depending on need:

```
// A simple weak dictionary. There are probably better versions out there. 
// I just threw this together.
struct WeakDict<Key: AnyObject, Value>: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {
    struct Box<T: AnyObject>: Hashable {
        let identifier: ObjectIdentifier
        weak var value: T?
        init(_ value: T) {
            self.identifier = ObjectIdentifier(value)
            self.value = value
        }

        static func ==(lhs: Box<T>, rhs: Box<T>) -> Bool {
            return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
        }
        var hashValue: Int { return identifier.hashValue }
    }

    private var dict: [Box<Key>: Value]

    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (Key, Value)...) {
        dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: elements.map { (Box($0), $1) })
    }

    private mutating func garbageCollect() {
        dict = dict.filter { (key, _) in key.value != nil }
    }

    subscript(_ key: Key) -> Value? {
        get {
            return dict[Box(key)]
        }
        set {
            garbageCollect()
            dict[Box(key)] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

With that, usage is almost identical:

```
private var lastValues: WeakDict<ViewController, Int> = [:]

extension ViewController {
    private var lastValue: Int {
        get { return lastValues[self] ?? 0 }
        set { lastValues[self] = newValue }
    }

    func checkIfBiggerThanLastNumber(_ number: Int) -> Bool {
        let savedLast = lastValue
        lastValue = number
        return number > savedLast
    }
}
```

Comment: This is, if I understand correctly, essentially what `objc_setAssociatedObject` does, but the latter does have the ability to automatically clean up memory when the object is deallocated. I dunno, if you're working with an `NSObject` subclass like `NSViewController`, I'd just use that. You can argue that it's un-Swifty since it uses the Objective-C runtime, but, then, so does `NSViewController`.........

Comment: Yes and yes. For NSObject subclasses I would (and do) definitely use `objc_setAssociatedObject`. This is just how you would do it without the runtime and for objects that aren't bridged to ObjC.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are best avoided. I would recommend making your var a private instance variable rather than a global.

It's reasonable to have private variables that are added to the object to support "native" extensions. (An extension that is defined in the same source file as the original object is really just a way of grouping code, since it is "baked into" the base object.

Using `objc_setAssociatedObject` for adding storage to `NSObject` subclasses is an option for extensions that extend other classes. You need to be aware that there is a small time penalty, but unless you're referencing an associated object repeatedly in a loop, it's not likely to be an issue. It also requires that the object be an Objective-C object, which **also** has a small time penalty.

Using `objc_setAssociatedObject` does also make your Swift code Apple-only. if you are building code that you intend to use on Linux, it's not really an option.